# How does one go about finding a specific directory out of a jar/zip file in java?

Tags: java, jar, directory

I have been working on this for quite a few hours. I can't seem to find the issue to this problem. Essentially what I have is this:

I have a jar, let's call it "a.jar"

I need to get the directory "z" and it's contents from "a.jar", but "z" isn't in the root directory of "a.jar".

"z" is in "/x/y/" and "/x/y/" is in "a.jar", so it looks like this:

"a.jar/x/y/z/"

I hope that's a decent explanation. By the way, "a.jar" is what everything is running out of, so its in the class path obviously.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using the normal zip/jar utility classes, or just getting to it as a classpath resource?

Comment: I'm using the normal zip/jar utilities (ZipEntry), but they don't work very well with sub-directories.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830581/getting-a-directory-inside-a-jar

Answer (score 3):

Basically for each ZipEntry you have to check if it isDirectory() and parse that also.
Checkout this link:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip49.html

LE:

Here is a complete example that extracts the files from the jar, and if you specify a specific path it will extract only that folder:

```
public void doUnzip(String inputZip, String destinationDirectory, String specificPath)
        throws IOException {
    int BUFFER = 2048;
    File sourceZipFile = new File(inputZip);
    File unzipDestinationDirectory = new File(destinationDirectory);
    unzipDestinationDirectory.mkdir();

    ZipFile zipFile;
    // Open Zip file for reading
    zipFile = new ZipFile(sourceZipFile, ZipFile.OPEN_READ);

    // Create an enumeration of the entries in the zip file
    Enumeration<?> zipFileEntries = zipFile.entries();

    // Process each entry
    while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        // grab a zip file entry
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();

        if(specificPath != null){
            if(entry.getName().startsWith(specificPath) == false)
                continue;
        }

        File destFile = new File(unzipDestinationDirectory, entry.getName());

        // create the parent directory structure if needed
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            // extract file if not a directory
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                        zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
                // establish buffer for writing file
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                // write the current file to disk
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,
                        BUFFER);

                // read and write until last byte is encountered
                for (int bytesRead; (bytesRead = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1;) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    zipFile.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Unzip unzip = new Unzip();
    try {
        unzip.doUnzip("test.jar", "output", "x/y/z");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing that, I am unable to get a list of the files from z, though.

Answer (score 1):

> ..(ZipEntry), but they don't work very well with sub-directories.

They work just fine.  Iterate the entries and simply check the path equates to that sub-directory.  If it does, add it to a list (or process it, whatever).