# Get all images within directory - within jar file

Tags: java, resources, io, classpath

I have a folder inside my project that has 238 images. I want to be able to find all images within the directory.

I'm currently accessing all these images like this:

```
File directory = new File(FileNameGuesser.class.getResource(DIRECTORY).getPath());
for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
    // filter, process, etc.
}
```

This works fine within Eclipse. However, when I export to a jar file, `FileNameGuesser.class.getResource(DIRECTORY)` returns `C:\Users\...\file.jar!\org\...` (because it's zipped, I assume) and the method breaks.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**: If possible, I'd like to find a solution that works both in Eclipse *and* in the jar that's deployed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a directory inside a .jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830581/getting-a-directory-inside-a-jar)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well it could be seen as a duplicate but there are other answers than the one supplied in your link. I supplied a fully functional answer that differs from those.

Comment: @maba  ..Just as you might have provided an answer on the linked  question.  Many things are possible. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well yes I could have but that would have drowned among all the other answers there and the question is rather old and would get less attention.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't *really* possible in any nice and clean way.

It would be nice to be able to do `.getClass().getResources("/pictures/*.jpg")` (or something), but we can't.

The best you can do is cheat a little. If you know the name of the jar file where the images are stored, you can use either the `JarFile` or `ZipFile` APIs to get a listing:

```
ZipFile zipFile = null;
try {

    zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("...")); // Path to your Jar
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

        // Here, I've basically looked for the "pictures" folder in the Zip
        // You will need to provide the appropriate value
        if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().startsWith("pictures")) {

            // Basically, from here you should have the full name of the
            // image.  You should be able to then construct a resource path
            // to the image to load it...

            // URL url = getClass().getResource("/" + entry.getName());
            System.out.println(entry.getName());

        }

    }

} catch (Exception exp) {

    exp.printStackTrace();

} finally {


    try {
        zipFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

A better solution would be not to embedded these images in your jar, if you don't know their names in advance.

Embedded resources really should be known by name to your application in advance.

As suggested by AndrewThompson, you could generate a list of resources, add this to your Jar file. At runtime, you would load this file and have access to all the resources.

Comment: `new ZipFile(new File("..."));`  Will not work in an applet or JWS app.  The URL will always point back to the server, even if the resource is cached.  If the resources **are** cached they will typically be loose files (in the JWS cache, at least) as opposed to Zip or Jar style archives.  Note that a ZipInputStream can be obtained for an URL.  See the linked 'duplicate' accepted answer for more details.

Comment: That makes sense. So does `zipFile.entries()` recursively get all files and folders within the zip/jar?

Comment: @AndrewThompson +1 for extended points. I did say it was cheat, maybe I should have said it was hack.  Better to have these resources out side the Jar/Zip

Comment: @WChargin yes and no.  `zipFile.getEntries()` will return EVERYTHING in the Zip/Jar, you don't need to perform recursion like you would for a directory on the file system

Comment: Everybody, got check out the link that AndrewThompson has provided.  His idea of using an URL and ZipStream is a better approach to using a File reference!

Comment: @SatishPandey No - it's a hack.  I relies on you knowing the resource (Jar/Zip) file to begin with.  It could suffer from locked files and I don't think it's very portable. It does work, but I'd be reluctant to rely on it

Comment: *"If possible, I'd like to find a solution that works both **in Eclipse** and in the jar that's deployed.*"  I feel this is better off solved by using a build tool to compile/jar/(sign/)run the code and use a method suited to a Jar.  -- There is yet another method of getting a list of content, but it also requires a build tool.  It is, create a list of target files and put it in a known location in the Jar.  Retrieve the list from the known location at run-time, read it for the list.

Comment: I ended up creating a list as you suggested; if you'd put that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: @WChargin You never tried with PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` provided by Spring.

```
public class SpringResourceLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

        // Ant-style path matching
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("/pictures/**");

        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            System.out.println("resource = " + resource);
            InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
            BufferedImage img =  ImageIO.read(is);
            System.out.println("img.getHeight() = " + img.getHeight());
            System.out.println("img.getWidth() = " + img.getWidth());
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't do anything fancy with the returned `Resource` but you get the picture.

Add this to your maven dependency (if using maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This will work directly from within Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ *and* in the jar that's deployed.

Running from within IntelliJ gives me the following output:

```
resource = file [C:\Users\maba\Development\stackoverflow\Q12016222\target\classes\pictures\BMW-R1100S-2004-03.jpg]
img.getHeight() = 768
img.getWidth() = 1024
```

Running from command line with executable jar gives me the following output:

```
C:\Users\maba\Development\stackoverflow\Q12016222\target>java -jar Q12016222-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
resource = class path resource [pictures/BMW-R1100S-2004-03.jpg]
img.getHeight() = 768
img.getWidth() = 1024
```