# How do I use a java.io.FilenameFilter to retrieve a list of .mp3 filenames from a directory?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to create a playlist of songs to be played by my media player:

I want to get a way to gather an array of files - from a folder named 'Songs' in the src files    ...........

And then send the files through as a playlist for:

```
//mp3 player
String bob = getClass().getResource("Songs/Sing.m4a").toExternalForm();
Media lol = new Media(bob);
MediaPlayer myMedia = new MediaPlayer(lol);



//play button for mp3 player - in My Library scene

public void audioPlayerButtons(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (actionEvent.getSource() == playbtn) {
        myMedia.play();

        nowPlaying.setText("Now Playing...");
        songPlayingName.setText("Sing - Ed Sheeran");


    } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == stopbtn) {
        myMedia.stop();

        nowPlaying.setText("Stopped");
        songPlayingName.setText("-");

    } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == pausebtn) {
        myMedia.pause();

        nowPlaying.setText("Paused");
    }
}

public void forwardAudio(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (actionEvent.getSource() == forwardbtn) {
        //mp3 player
        nowPlaying.setText("Now Playing...");
        songPlayingName.setText("No Better - Lorde");


        if (actionEvent.getSource() == forwardbtn) {

            myMedia.pause();

            if (actionEvent.getSource() == stopbtn) {
                myMedia.stop();
            }

        }
    }
}

public void backAudio(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (actionEvent.getSource() == backwardbtn) {
        //mp3 player

        nowPlaying.setText("Now Playing...");
        songPlayingName.setText("Dark Horse - Kate Perry");


    }

}
```

Comment: *"from a folder named 'Songs' in the src files"* - You can't, or not easily.  Create a text file which contains a list of all the "songs", store this along with the files in the `src` directory and use `getClass().getResource(...)` or ``getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` to load it.  Then use this list to load each resource

Comment: A possible [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247669/read-directory-inside-jar-with-inputstreamreader/18247809#18247809), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015747/get-all-images-within-directory-within-jar-file/12015819#12015819), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758105/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-within-a-jar/18758724#18758724)

Comment: "from a folder named 'Songs' in the src files" - the .java files are (normally) not included in a Java application. Java applications consists of .class files. Additional resources must be provided somehow, for example by providing hard coded absolute / relative links to somewhere or by including additonal files in the jar (if you create a jar) ... .

Comment: For information about a FileNameFilter check java.io.File#list(FilenameFilter) or java.io.File#listFiles(FilenameFilter) A basic implementation for .mp3 files in the current directory would be FilenameFilter fnf = new FilenameFilter() {
   @Override
   public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3");
   }
  };