# What could possibly prevent a runnable JAR from opening?

Tags: java, image, file, jar, resources

I'm trying to export my java project (it's a game) into a runnable JAR file but, unfortunately, even though I did: File>Export>Java>Runnable JAR file>Chose my main class correctly, when I try to open it, it doesn't do anything (on windows) or open in the menu bar and then close unexpectedly (on mac).

I suspect this to happen because of the way I load my resources. Can anyone tell me what could possibly cause this?

EDIT: This is where the problem is, I get a NullPointerException in resources.lenght in the first for loop: This method scans a folder in my resources and reads every images that conform to a platform type (the game is a platformer) from my resources and save them in an ArrayList.

```
private void readImages() {
    URL urlFolder = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("platforms");
    File[] resources = new File(urlFolder.getPath()).listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
        String fileName = resources[i].getName();
        String name = fileName.substring(0,          fileName.indexOf('_')).toUpperCase();
        try {
            EnumPlatformTypes type = EnumPlatformTypes.valueOf(name);
            variantsForType[getTypeNumber(type)]++;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erreur de nommage du fichier " + fileName);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TYPES; i++) {
        platformSprites.add(new Image[variantsForType[i]]);
        String type = EnumPlatformTypes.values()[i].toString();
        for(int k = 0; k < variantsForType[i] ; k++) {
            String fileName = type.substring(0, 1) + type.substring(1, type.length()).toLowerCase() + "_" + k + ".png";
            URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("platforms/" + fileName);
            if(url == null) {
                System.out.println("Incapable de lire le fichier d'image " + fileName);
                return;
            }
            try {
                platformSprites.get(i)[k] = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException lors de la lecture     avec ImageIO");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

If you know if this code can prevent the jar from opening, I'd appreciate if you could tell me where is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Run the JAR using `java -jar <file>` so you can see what the error is. Add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: Try running it from the command line (`java -jar ...`). Do any of your errors get printed?

Comment: (Thanks for the command I didn't know it)

So the error is a nullPointerException on this line:
    for(int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
As I suspected the error comes from this part of my code but I still can't figure why I get this error... It works perfectly in Eclipse.

Comment: `File[] resources = new File(urlFolder.getPath()).listFiles();` <-- this will work with a flat file tree, but within a jar?

Comment: Also, do not catch `Exception`! This will also catch all unchecked exceptions (including `NullPointerException` among others)

Comment: Exactly, but how can I make it work with a jar? Any idea? I'm kind of new with runnable JAR files...

Comment: @fge what catch should I use?

Comment: An enum's `.valueOf()` throws `IllegalArgumentException`, this is the one you should catch (it is also unchecked, but at least you won't mask other unchecked exceptions this way)

Comment: @fge Yes Java 7 and I'll change the exception to IllegalArgumentException then

Comment: OK, then see my answer, you have a sketch for a solution. This was undoable with Java 6 so easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which should work given that you use Java 7... The "trick" is to use the new file API. Oracle JDK provides a `FileSystem` implementation which can be used to peek into/modify ZIP files, and that include jars!

Preliminary: grab `System.getProperty("java.class.path", ".")`, split against `:`; this will give you all entries in your defined classpath.

First, define a method to obtain a `FileSystem` out of a classpath entry:

```
private static final Map<String, ?> ENV = Collections.emptyMap();

//

private static FileSystem getFileSystem(final String entryName)
    throws IOException
{
    final String uri = entryName.endsWith(".jar") || entryName.endsWith(".zip"))
        ? "jar:file:" + entryName : "file:" + entryName;
    return FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create(uri), ENV);
}
```

Then create a method to tell whether a path exists within a filesystem:

```
private static boolean pathExists(final FileSystem fs, final String needle)
{
    final Path path = fs.getPath(needle);
    return Files.exists(path);
}
```

Use it to locate your `"platform"`.

Once you have the correct `FileSystem`, use it to walk your directory using `.getPath()` as above and open a `DirectoryStream` using `Files.newDirectoryStream()`.

And don't forget to .close() a FileSystem once you're done with it!

---

**EDIT 1** Here is a sample `main()` demonstrating how to read all the root entries of a jar:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
    throws IOException
{
    final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.emptyMap();
    final String jarName = "/opt/sunjdk/1.6/current/jre/lib/plugin.jar";
    final URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + jarName);
    final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
    final Path dir = fs.getPath("/");
    for (Path entry : Files.newDirectoryStream(dir))
        System.out.println(entry);
}
```

---

**EDIT 2** Here is a sample main which allows you to print the content of your classpath, plus the MIME type associated with it:

```
public final class Foo
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final ClassLoader loader = Foo.class.getClassLoader();

        final URL[] urLs = ((URLClassLoader) loader).getURLs();

        for (final URL url : urLs) {
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(url.toURI())));
        }
    }
}
```

You will see that the return code of `Files.probeContentType()` is:

- `application/x-java-archive` for JARs,
- `inode/directory` for directories.

Which means you can use the return code of this method to build the correct URI and therefore open the correct `FileSystem`.

Comment: You should add that as an Answer to the Question I linked to!

Comment: When I try to get the path using System.getProperty("java.class.path", ".") and convert that path to a URI, I get an error because the path contains backslashes. Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: @user3421883 using Windows? ;) Just joking... I know what to do to prevent this error. Wait for post update

Answer (score 2):

You say that the exception occurs here:

```
URL urlFolder = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("platforms");
File[] resources = new File(urlFolder.getPath()).listFiles();
for(int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {            // THIS LINE
```

That means that `resources` is `null`.

And that in turn means that `listFiles()` returned `null`.

And that means that whatever `urlFolder.getPath()` returned is NOT a resolvable pathname for a directory in the filesystem.  (See the [javadoc for `listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)),

Which is expected ... if the "platforms" resource is in a JAR file.  (In that case, the URL will be a "jar:" URL, and `getPath()` will not return what you need.  Indeed, it cannot, because the directory name you need is not in the file system at all.)

Here is a question whose answers offer some possible solutions to this problem:

- [Getting a directory inside a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830581/getting-a-directory-inside-a-jar)

... but it is not pretty.  Or @fge's Java 7+ solution.

Comment: Java 7 makes it sooo much easier than the proposed solution in that last answer ;)